# Sqlite3 aiogram перезаписывает столбец в базе данных если человек уже там есть, а мне нужно что-бы бд записывала в новую строчку

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

помогите пожалуйста
Sqlite3 aiogram  перезаписывает строчку в базе данных если человек уже там есть, а мне нужно что-бы бд записывала в новую строчку.

```
db = sqlite3.connect("mercury.db")
cur = db.cursor()
db.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
c = db.cursor()
c.execute(
'create table if not exists chat(id primary key ,number, user , nick , first_name, last_name , country, data)')

@dp.message_handler(commands=["register"])
async def ggssd(message: types.Message):
    phone = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(selective=True)
    b1 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Зарегистрироваться", request_contact=True)
    phone.add(b1)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Чтобы продолжить Регистрацию вам необходимо, Нажать кнопку Зарегистрироваться',
                       parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=phone)

c.execute("select * from chat")
try:
    c.execute("insert into chat values(? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? , ?)", (
        message.chat.id, message.contact.phone_number, "@" + str(message.chat.username), message.chat.first_name,
        None,
        None, None, None))
    db.commit()
except:
    c.execute("update chat set number == ? where id == ?", (message.contact.phone_number, message.chat.id))


c.execute("select * from chat")
    c.execute("update chat set first_name == ? where id == ?", (str(hname), message.chat.id)).fetchone()
    db.commit()
    c.execute("update chat set last_name == ? where id == ?", (str(kname), message.chat.id)).fetchone()
    db.commit()
    c.execute("update chat set data == ? where id == ?", (str(datayr), message.chat.id)).fetchone()
    db.commit()
    c.execute("update chat set country == ? where id == ?", (str(cook), message.chat.id)).fetchone()
    db.commit()
    gh = 0
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы оставили только ту часть кода где у вас идёт запись в БД, а также ваши попытки решить это (без разницы правильные они или нет).

Comment: У вас id - primary_key (должен быть уникальным), что не даёт вам создать несколько строк с одним user_id. Создайте столбец user_id, а id сделайте autoincrement (чтобы сам добавлял уник. значение), после чего делайте только insert (update не добавляет новую строку а обновляет существующие)